# ASP.NET : How to get the usernames of the Windows system

Tags: asp.net, .net, active-directory, ldap, windows-authentication

I want to build a website in which username and password will be passed by the user and these credentials should be checked against the username and password of windows account on which the website is hosted using LDAP authentication. How can it be possible ? Is it necessary to have domain name for this checking ?
Thank You.

Comment: `Environment.UserName Property`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via ActiveDirectory authentication

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, userName, password))
        {
            userInfo.IsAuthenticated = pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
            if (userInfo.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                string lastName = userPrincipal.Surname;                
                string givenName = userPrincipal.GivenName;                                 
            }
        }
```

Comment: So It is necessary to pass domain name which is second parameter here, right ?

Comment: Yes domain name is required.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to implement windows authentication in asp.net, please read the article linked to below for a deep understanding of the configurations you need to do.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94612/Windows-Authentication